# If we all have taken different incarnations due to our karma, how can we explain what might have caused our first incarnation

Tags: vedas, bhagavad-gita, karma, moksha, paramatma

My question is - If we all have taken different incarnations due to our karma, how can we explain what might have caused our first incarnation? If the ultimate goal is to attain moksha/reunite with Parabrahman/Supreme Being, why did we leave Him in the first place?

Comment: Brahma sent forth his mind born sons. Prajapatis who created beings coming from soul of universe apparently manifesting separately, but are part of Brahman.

Comment: This is something that I have always wondered. How all of this started? I couldn't find any reference in the scriptures on the same. It is also said that there is no beginning and the end but not sure how do we explain the very first occurrence when everything was created for the first time.

Comment: Brahman is strictly impersonal without likes and dislikes, no favorites etc. This is a question asked in the Rig Veda- what was there in the beginning? Read the Nasadiya Sukta. Because of these deep questions which may unnerve common people, there were and there should be restrictions on who can teach the Veda authoritatively.